# Length of singly linkedlist in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I created a singly linked list to find the length of it and for some reason it's printing only 1. I defined `LengthOfLinkedList` method and there I am trying to increase the counter to keep track of the length of the linked list but it's not working properly.

```
public class LengthList {



public static int LengthOfLinkedList(List head){

    int count = 0;
    List current = head;
    while(current != null){
        current = current.next;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}



    public static void main (String[] args){

        List myList = new List(1);
        myList.next = new List(2);
        myList.next.next = new List(3);
        myList.next.next.next = new List(4);
        myList.next.next.next.next = new List(5);


        System.out.println("\n Length LinkedList : \n"+LengthOfLinkedList(myList));
    }
}

class List {
    int value;
    List next;
    public List(int k){
        value = k;
        next = null;
    }

    public String toString(){

        List cur = this;
        String output = "";
        while(cur != null){

            output+=cur.value+"-->";
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return output+"Tail";
    }
}
```

It's printing the length as only 01. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: It ptints "Length LinkedList : 5". Try to recompile your project:) You may use debugger to investigate what has happened. Btw, what is a reason to create linked list manually and with out of generics?

Comment: @user996142 In Eclipse I did `Project-->Clean` and then `Run` the project again. It's printing 1 only. Am I recompiling correctly in eclipse?

Comment: Yes. I do not know why it is 1. Use debugger to investigate: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: I got 5 as well. Why don't you create a new file and copy/paste it.